# Count the occurrence of one element in multiple other arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, key-value

I need to find occurrence of all element of one array in multiple other arrays.

For example, my input array is `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`

First test array is `["a", "c", "d"]`

Second test array is `["a"]`

Third test array is `["a", "c"]`

My Result array should be `{"a": "100%", "b": "0%", "c": "66%", "d": "33%", "e": "0%"}`

Here, in the result array the keys are coming from the input array and the respective values are generating from the number of occurrence among the three test arrays.

- "a" occurs 3 times in 3 test arrays so it gives 100%
- "c" occurs 2 times in 3 test arrays and gives 66%
- "d" occurs 1 time and gives 33%
- "b" and "e" don't occur so it gives 0% as values.

I try to find solutions but couldn't find any. Can anyone please help me out?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using nested `forEach` loop

```js
function occurances(arr, arrays){
  const object = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(x => [x, 0]));
  arrays.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(x => object[x]++)
  })
  
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => [k, v/arrays.length * 100]))
}

console.log(occurances([1,2,3,4,5], [[1,2], [2, 3], [1, 2]]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! ^_^